# IOS CGContextSelectFont and CGContextShowText deprecated what to use now

Tags: ios, deprecation-warning

In iOS7 CGContextSelectFont and CGContextShowText is deprecated. Deprecation message says that I have to use Core Text, but I don't know which is the exact equivalent of this piece of code:

```
- (void)drawTextInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGContextSelectFont(context, [self.font.fontName cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]], self.font.pointSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);




    CGRect textRect = [self textRectForBounds:self.bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:1];
    CGContextSetTextPosition(context, textRect.origin.x, textRect.origin.y + 5.0f);



    CGContextShowText(context, [self.text cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]], strlen([self.text cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalent replacement : `AttributedString`

```
[txtString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)
           withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans"                                                               size:12.0]
                            }];
```

Comment: How do you tell it to use the given graphics context?